# Can I use languages other than MQL4 on MetaTrader4?

Tags: c#, metatrader4, mql4

I have a task of migrating a C# market strategy to MetaTrader.

1. Is there any way to automate that job? (For example, is it possible to parse C# into it's AST, then make the translation?)
2. Does MetaTrader accept other languages by any means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Approach the task Bottom-Up -- Architecture-wise

Yes, you can simplify the trouble and make MT4 become a Node, which is **immediately** connected peer-to-peer to your **current** C# Market Strategy.

This alowed me to operate a **cluster-based computing** communicating massively parallel with a crowd of **MT4** nodes.

MT4 can become **`anEventFEED`**-er Node via a more complex "*Scaleable Formal Cummunication Framework*" in a very intelligent manner.

Do you wish to have a **CLI-interface to command your MT4 node(s)** -- one as `anEventFEED`-er, another as **`anXtoACTOR`** Node -- selectively, with a syntax & grammar of CLI-instructions ( not speaking about test-automation et al ...)?

Do you wish to have a central <***syslog***> daemon to off-load HFT-traffic loaded MT4 node(s) and automate + administer scripted monitoring & maintenance tasks?

Do you wish to have an external **GPU-computing engine/cluster** to communicate in a Client/Server manner with MT4 EA on a per-tickEvent basis?

**ZeroMQ** and/or **nanomsg** frameworks will allow you to design and develop many-to-many ( node-network-wise ) & any-to-any ( implementation language-wise ) systems.

MT4/MQL4 has a direct smart wrapper for ZeroMQ >>> thanks to Austen Conrad on GitHub **MQL4ZMQ**

**ZeroMQ** >>> thanks to it's great team has many language bindings - **C**/C++, Python, Java, R, even Erlang, ...

So your Project may jump start on rock solid grounds & independent of any particular architecture gridlocks ( DLL moving sands et al )

Engineering built-ins save you a lot of time and efforts and avoid re-inventing wheel

Comment: @Viclib There are many traps on the MT4 side on the way to **"move a C# market strategy"** to this domain. Cross-compilation is not that simple if going to produce a professional-grade service. Tried to get in touch with you, Viclib, to offer further help on this effort, but  **Error: ENOENT, stat '/home/vh/Viclib/index.html'** appeared.

Comment: @Viclib How is your Conversion Project going, Viclib? Anyway PF2015

Comment: PF2015! I didn't engage this job for lack of C# knowledge :( - I shifted my focus to functional programming instead. Thanks for asking, how are you?

Comment: Thanks, I am fine. Good luck in Fun-programming, Vic. Still more ideas than available time to review & implement each one. Keep hacking, Vic! In case you spot a similarly interesting FX/Quant job/Project flying around you, do let me know :o)

Answer (score 3):

How about GET/POST requests and a web based text API service?

You could use your C# strategy to update a web based text file with a ternary signal:

```
-1 SELL
 0 HOLD
 1 BUY
```

Then use MQL4 to read the text file once a minute for a trade signal.

As far as technically how to do this; unfortunately I'm a python programmer not MQL4 or C#, so I can't help.

Comment: **FYI**: a file-based, web-server operated, GET/POST accessed on a one-minute sampling basis is hard to imagine in a world, where ***milliseconds*** are "ages" and ***microseconds*** matter and ***nanoseconds*** are fought to be shaved-off where possible...

Comment: @user3666197, in my experience most quantitative traders are not HFT traders... which beyond the hype is a really specialized field.  This technique would be more than adequate for trading hourly candles, which constitute most retail transactions.

Comment: sure, ***nanoseconds*** matter in large-scale computational models, which need not be just for HFT-sharks. **Still** H1-candles have increased transaction flow int the last few tens of seconds, if you wish, where the final Close-price gets cross-fired between bearish and bullish motivated forces and even H1-based strategy has a fair reason to have minimum TimeDOMAIN "blind-spot" dead-locked in an uncontrollable transaction latency. If something may take a few miliseconds, why to spend hundreds of these or even a few seconds fot the same answer? **The FOREX river never waits for someone.**

Comment: I see where you are coming from.  Most strategies I dev depend upon "all in" "all out" about once weekly based on H1 and H12 indications.   Nanoseconds really don't matter all that much from this perspective; I only check price once a minute.   I agree that if your trade frequency is more in line with scalping noise than slaying dragons this technique would fail.

Comment: :) Nice wallpaper on SAR Harmonica.

Answer (score 1):

short answer  is no,  however,  there is a faculty in mql  to import dlls.  so you could wrap your c#  lib with a c++/cli  lib that  exposes functionally via function exports,  you could even run a  timer in mql and implement a rudimentary message pump.

Update: MT4 can only access standard calls of unmanaged DLLs. the reason you have to use a c++ wrapper is that c++ DOES have the capability to create unmanaged standard calls. any other language that you can create standard calls with can also work.

Furthermore you need a wrapper just in case you want to use other languages which does not support standard calls.  You may just write your entire code in c++ and the whole wrapper concept will be obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use C# by using some 3rd party solutions like NQuotes http://www.nquotes.net/ , which is essentially a ready-made DLL for a general usage (like Dmitry said, you can create your own, but it involves a bit of work).