# Pull data from website into CSV and refreshes every five minutes

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4

I'm developing a program in MQL4 that's going to require a few snippets of data pulled from a specific web page.

How can I dump this into a `.csv` file every 5 minutes?

I'm stuck on how to am I going to go about this.

### Structure

1. Some pieces of data dumped from a `.html` page
2. Plug into `.csv` file
3. Read by MQL4

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Answer (score 3):

Since your Question is so general (not specific coding issue), and it is too wide. I will offer a generalize answer to point you at the right direction. You need to do your own research.

**PART 1 - Schedule an Event**

- In your EA, in the OnInit(); create a timer with `EventSetTimer(5*60)`.
- That will trigger the event OnTimer() event. 5*60 = 5 minutes.
- In that `OnTimer()` event, call your download program (see Part 2)

**PART 2 - DOWNLOAD HTML**

- You can achieve this without using 3rd-party DLLs. The built-in Windows `Wininet.DLL` has the right APIs for this:

  ```
  import "wininet.dll" //Put a # in-front of import
      int InternetAttemptConnect (int x);
      int InternetOpenW(string sAgent, int lAccessType, 
                              string sProxyName = "", string sProxyBypass = "", 
                              int lFlags = 0);
      int InternetOpenUrlW(int hInternetSession, string sUrl, 
                                  string sHeaders = "", int lHeadersLength = 0,
                                  int lFlags = 0, int lContext = 0);
      int InternetReadFile(int hFile, int& sBuffer[], int lNumBytesToRead, 
                                  int& lNumberOfBytesRead[]);
      int InternetCloseHandle(int hInet);
  import    //Put a # in-front of import
  ```
- That should get your started on the download part (do some research on your own).
- First is to create a browser session using the `OpenW`, then open the URL with the `OpenURLW`, then read the content of the page with the ReadFile API; and finally, close the session with `CloseHandle`.
- Once you have the HTML in a string variable within your MT4 code, all you need is to massage it the way you want it.

**PART 3 - To Write To a .CSV**

To perform File write operation, you are looking at the `FileOpen()`, `FileWriteString()` and `FileClose()` MQL4 functions.

**PART 4 - To Read the .CSV**

- To read the CSV file, it is as simple as using the `FileReadString()`.
- You can split the string into CSV by using the `StringSplit()` function.

Comment: Looks like a good answer. However I generally recommend against adding meta-commentary in answers - most of the people reading this are not the original poster, and they don't want to read complaints. You have two options: you can add that kind of advice as a comment under the question, and/or you could vote to close as too broad (I have done that now). As you've discovered, low-effort questions can result in making a good answer and not even receiving a reply, but at least this will benefit other readers!

Answer (score 0):

### A Short Version

1. **Yes,** possible -- via an MQL4-independent external process, being connected via ZeroMQ to the `.ex4` due to control and synchronisation needs ( ZMQ has ports/wrappers for many production-grade environments, so ready to integrate MQL4 with whatever one needs
2. **Yes,** possible -- *Elementary, dear Watson...* ( ref. #1, may be skipped, if needed )
3. **Yes,** possible -- May be available in a process-to-process ( ref. #1 and #2 )

---

[Check this and other MQL4/ZeroMQ posts on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732222/can-i-use-languages-other-than-mql4-on-metatrader4/24196012#24196012)

[Another MQL4 Real-time output, being remote-logged and animated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750485/3666197)